# Ksqldb High Availability - how to reach it

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka, ksqldb

I’m working with a ksqldb server deployed in Kubernetes, and since some time ago it crashed for some reason, I want to implement High Availability as described in https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/operate-and-deploy/high-availability/

We are deploying the server with docker, so the properties that we put inside the config file are:

KSQL_KSQL_STREAMS_NUM_STANDBY_REPLICAS: “2” 
KSQL_KSQL_QUERY_PULL_ENABLE_STANDBY_READS: “true” 
KSQL_KSQL_HEARTBEAT_ENABLE: “true” 
KSQL_KSQL_LAG_REPORTING_ENABLE: “true”

When doing so and restarting the server, I can see that only the first 2 properties are properly set, and I can see the last two (for example with SHOW PROPERTIES from the ksqdb CLI).

Do you have an idea about why I can’t see them?

Do I have to manually deploy a second ksqldb server with the same ksql.service.id?
If this is the case, what is the correct way to do it? Are there particular properties to be set?

Comment: Yes, you should have more than one replica of your ksql server (use deployment + service, not just pod). Environment variables of one container doesn't do that.

Comment: @OneCricketeer thank you for the answer, what do you mean with "use deployment + service, not just pod"?
Do you have a piece of documentation that explains exactly how to set up a replica? I didn't find it

Comment: Kubernetes documentation? Deployment has a replicas field... https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/blob/master/charts/cp-ksql-server/templates/deployment.yaml#L15